# Scheduled Time Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, xcode5

I'm trying to initiate a delay in my code so that when the action gets to that part of the code, everything stops, for as long as the delay is scheduled. I already have setup the time delay, it's just a matter of how the code is supposed to execute.

This is the time delay that I've employed in my project:

```
NSDate *timeDelay = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:timeDelay];
```

As you can see, this snippet inputs a 5 second delay. The problem I'm having, is that when I employ this code it doesn't do what I would expect it to do. Below is the function I'm trying to run:

```
- (IBAction)executeProgram
{
    UIAlertView *delayAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Delay"
                                message:@"This message follows with a 5 second delay."
                                delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    // Enable when time is working properly
    [delayAlert show];

    NSDate *timeDelay = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:timeDelay];

    // dismisses the alert
    [delayAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

I would expect this code to first, display the alert, wait 5 seconds, and then dismiss the alert. However, that doesn't happen. Instead what happens, is that when I click on the button, there is a five second delay **first**, then the alert pops up and almost instantaneously dismisses itself. I've tried this with another snippet of code for the time delay, with the same reaction.

```
CFAbsoluteTime startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

for (int x = 0; x<=5000; x++)
{
    NSLog(@"%i",x);
}

CFAbsoluteTime endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFAbsoluteTime elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why would the delay execute before the alert pops up?

Comment: As a side note, forcing the user to stare at an alert view for a period of time like this makes for a poor experience and is probably warned against in the HIG.

Comment: @joshcaswell This isn't an application that I plan on publishing to the App Store, but one that I would be using for personal use.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The other question is similar, so thank you for pointing it out to me. I wasn't aware it existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're sleeping (and blocking) the thread that the alert should be presented from (the main/UI thread). I recommend you use `dispatch_after` to sleep asynchronously, and then call back to the main thread after the 5 seconds has passed to dismiss the alert. Something like this:

```
UIAlertView *delayAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Delay"
                            message:@"This message follows with a 5 second delay."
                            delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[delayAlert show];

double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [delayAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```